# Today Extension (iOS widget) to get message from shared code framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, widget, today-extension

I have an iOS project with three targers: 
-Main App (parent)
-Today Extension (widget)
-Framework that holds some objects and methods, that are common to the parent app and the widget. Those members are being accessed from the app and the widget.

Both the app and the widget can send messages to the framework, but the framework cannot send messages to them. I cannot invoke app or widget method from the framework.

My problem is that: from the widget, I invoke some async method in the shared framework. Since the method is async, the widget does not know when the invoked method has finished its task. 
I need the framework to notify the widget somehow when its method has finished, and trigger a response method in a widget class.
Is there a way to send message from the framework to the widget? I do not want to use the UserDefaults to share that information between targets.

Comment: Why not provide a completion block in the async calls to the framework?  Or, define and use a delegate protocol to give the Framework classes an API to invoke that's independent of your app-specific code?

Comment: How would completion block asist me? Lets say the completion block updated some object in the framework. I need to be able to notify the app of its work done. As I said, the problem is that I have one way communication: from the app to the framework - not vice versa.

Comment: I can post a more thorough explanation, but before I do, I want to make sure I'm clear about what you mean by "one way communication":  do you mean that, because the Framework doesn't include or share any headers, declarations, etc. from or with the app (as it shouldn't), the Framework has no direct means of communication state back to the app?

Comment: Ok, let me explain: I have a project with main app and an extension. 
Since the extension runs in a separate proccess, there's no communication between them: the extension can't invoke methods from the main app.
Thus, I added an embedded framework. In this framework, I write code used by both app & extension.
Problem: I can invoke framework methods from the extension, but not vice versa.
-The extension invokes a framework method
-Method performs async task
-In extension, the program moves on before async task is done

I need the framework to notify the extention when async task is done